# Button suddenly needs WithEvents variable

Tags: asp.net, button

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
```

"Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types"

Hello i am using visual studio and i been using some of the controls like button  etc,  i not sure what happened but when i added a button this error showed up .Its strange because it works just fine on my other pages and well it worked just fine on this page as well. Is there anything i might have changed by mistake that caused this? because all my other controls on this page were created  the same way and they work fine but when i try add new controls this error shows up!

Comment: Check the name of your Button

Answer (score 0):

Hey i solved my problem , sadly i didnt find what went wrong but what fixed it was taking some old backup pages and copy pasting the new added content into it.